# How to fix background-color(static) of table rows in HTML if the data changes dynamically?

Tags: php, html, css, background-color

I have an order table, where orders are going in and out, and I have to fix background-color of entire rows( I mean in every three lines the background color is changing in a loop).
For example:

```css
#orders tr:nth-child(3n+3) {
    background: #e7eff6;
}

#orders tr:nth-child(3n+4) {
    background: #d0e1f9;
}
    
#orders tr:nth-child(3n+2) {
    background: #adcbe3;
}
```

But there's a problem, because if an order is going in or an order is being canceled and going out, then the rows background-color is going to change, but I have to fix it and remain the color what firstly got.

So, I need to separate rows, not necessary by background-colors, but it must to be fixed if the data is changing dynamically.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: As the rows get generated, assign them a class which will map to a specific color defined in the CSS.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. If I delete an order and refresh, the following order will inherit the deleted row's bg-color.

Comment: Then just use a class which maps to an attribute of each row that never changes, e.g. its `id`. For example, if you want a maximum of three different colors, use `id % 3` to generate one of three unique class names which will always be consistent for that row.

Comment: I see, but how could I do that, in JS?

Comment: You don't do it in JS, you do it in PHP. If you show the code you use to generate a row, I can show you how to modify it to use a row's ID to generate one of three class names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use modulus *%* in JS for setting background color for rows once on load.
For example if your table have *id=tableId*, you can run something like that

```
let tableEl = document.getElementById("tableId");
let index = 0;
let colors = ["#e7eff6","#d0e1f9","#adcbe3"]
for (let trEl of tableEl.rows) {
    trEl.style.backgroundColor = colors[index % colors.length];
    index++;
}
```